# Выбор цветов для "ночной" темы

Tags: android, gui, ui, color, material-design

Пишу погодное приложение.

Для подбора цветов, чтобы следовать концепции Material Design, использовал ресурс https://www.materialpalette.com/.

Остановился на следующей цветовой схеме (см. рисунок ниже)

Сейчас решил добавить "ночную тему" (см рисунок ЕЩЕ ниже :-)

Я брал цвета "на глаз".

Существуют какие-либо гайды или ресурсы для подбора цветов для ночных тем? Как правильно подобрать цвета для ночной темы, следуя концепции Material Design?

Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Нашел любопытную [статейку](https://wp-dreams.com/articles/2014/03/picking-the-right-night-mode-colors-for-your-ui/) по первому вопросу.

1. Находим [картинку в спокойных темных тонах](http://neatdesigns.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/1531.jpg)
2. Загружаем в [pictaculous](http://www.pictaculous.com/)
3. [Profit](https://wp-dreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/palette.jpg)